# Aspects that affects the efficiency of OpenMP parallelism

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to parallel a big loop using OpenMP to improve its efficiency. Here is the main part of the toy code:

```
vector<int> config;
config.resize(indices.size());

omp_set_num_threads(2);
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 5000) firstprivate(config)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) { // the outer loop that I would like to parallel
#pragma omp simd
        for (int j = 0; j < indices.size(); ++j) { // pick some columns from a big ref_table
            config[j] = ref_table[i][indices[j]];
        }
        int index = GetIndex(config); // do simple computations on the picked values to get the index
#pragma omp atomic
        result[index]++;
    }
```

Then I found I cannot get improvements in efficiency if I use 2, 4, or 8 threads. The execution time of the parallel versions is generally greater than that of the sequential version. The outer loop has 10000 iterations and they are independent so I want multiple threads to execute those iterations in parallel.

I guess the reasons for performance decrease maybe include: private copies of `config`? or, random access of `ref_table`? or, expensive atomic operation? So what are the exact reasons for the performance decrease? More importantly, how can I get a shorter execution time?

Comment: What does `GetIndex` do? Any explicit or hidden memory allocations (like using a vector or list)?

Comment: How big is indices.size()?

Comment: `"or, random access of ref_table?"` Multiple threads accessing the same memory location is not a problem, as long as these accesses are strictly read-only. It will only become a problem if at least one of the threads performs a write operation on that location.

Comment: I think, as usual, your code is memory bound. It means that the speed of your program mainly depends on speed of memory read/write. Please read this answer, I think it may apply to your case as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503586/using-openmp-to-parallelize-a-loop-over-a-vector-c-objects/68507395#68507395

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It does not contain memory allocations. It contains some simple additions and multiplications.

Comment: @Laci The size of indices is less than 10 and no less than 2.

Comment: I don't think the `#pragma omp simd` should give any speedup even if `indices` were bigger because you are doing a gather operation in the inner loop which I can not imagine to profit from vectorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private copies of `config` or, random access of `ref_tables` are not problematic, I think the workload is very small, there are 2 potential issues which prevent efficient parallelization:

1. atomic operation is too expensive.
2. overheads are bigger than workload (it simply means that it is not worth parallelizing with OpenMP)

I do not know which one is more significant in your case, so it is worth trying to get rid of atomic operation. There are 2 cases:

a) If the `results` array is zero initialized you have to use:

`#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result[0:N]) schedule(static, 5000) firstprivate(config)` where `N` is the size of `result` array and delete `#pragma omp atomic`. Note that this works on OpenMP 4.5 or later. It is also worth removing `#parama omp simd` for a loop of 2-10 iterations. So, your code should look like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result[0:N]) schedule(static, 5000) firstprivate(config)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) { // the outer loop that I would like to parallel
        for (int j = 0; j < indices.size(); ++j) { // pick some columns from a big ref_table
            config[j] = ref_table[i][indices[j]];
        }
        int index = GetIndex(config); // do simple computations on the picked values to get the index
        result[index]++;
    }
```

b) If the `result` array is not zero initialized the solution is very similar, but use a temporary zero initialized array in the loop and after that add it to `result` array.

If the speed will not increase then your code is not worth parallelizing with OpenMP on your hardware.